# What is the most straight forward way to compute $H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z}_{k})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-cohomology

I'm trying to wrap my head around group cosmology, and I wanted to inquire what would be the most straight forward way to compute  $H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z}_{k})$? Would it be to use the fact that,
$$H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z}_{k}) \simeq \textrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_{n} }(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_{k})?$$
And then compute the ext, or is there a more straight forward way?

Comment: For group cohomology of cyclic groups, one way that usually works pretty easily is to just take a projective resolution to compute the ext.

Comment: If the action $\theta\colon \Bbb Z_n\rightarrow {\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_k)$ is injective then $H^s(\Bbb Z_n,\Bbb Z_k)=0$ for all $s\ge 1$.

Comment: For a straightforward way see also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682116/surjectivity-second-cohomology-of-cyclic-group).